# PHP - access function from a class

Tags: php, class, function

I have a class like:

```
class bla_bla extends WP_Widget {

  function boo(){
    return 'something';
  }

  ...
}
```

(it's a WordPress widget)

How can I access the `boo()` function from outside the class?
I want to assign the value returned by that function to a variable, like `$var = boo();`

Comment: Start reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either access it directly or by instantiating the class:

```
$blah = new bla_bla();
$var = $blah->boo();
```

or

```
$var = bla_bla::boo();
```

Answer (score 5):

You must have an instance of that class to call it, for example:

```
$widget = new bla_bla();
$var = $widget->boo();
```

Otherwise, you can add the "static" keyword to the boo() function, and you could call it like `$var = WP_Widget::boo();` but this changes the semantics and could break code.

Answer (score 3):

First you need an instance of the class. Then you call the method (if it's public). You should read some OOP tutorials as this is really basic stuff. See [Object Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/).

```
$bla = new bla_bla();
$var = $bla->boo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Short writing style:

```
$bla = (new bla_bla)->boo();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$bla = new bla_bla();
$var = $bla->boo();
```

Comment: but if I use new bla_bla(), wouldn't the class run other functions as well?

Answer (score 0):

$bla = new bla_bla();
$newbla = $bla->boo();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).