# What is the meaning of the arrow in prepared statements?

Tags: prepared-statement

what is the meaing of the " -> " in the following statement:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eventdb;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This link explains it very well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216296/php-access-function-from-a-class

Comment: Thanks a lot, testoo